# Issue with date pipe in angular for KHMER language

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, localization, date-pipe

```
       <span>{{
            value | date: 'E, dd/MM/yyyy':undefined:languageCode
        }}</span>
```

I have a scenario in which I need to pass the locale code corresponding to Cambodia's `KHMER` language. I tried multiple locale codes but they didn't work as expected.
Could anyone please help me in finding the locale code for the `KHMER` language of Cambodia?

The above code is working fine for Chinese, English...

Comment: Hello, we need more information. Please upload an example of your code to Stackblitz, and provide more information, like screenshots, expected result, etc.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-nwmu7a?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You just to register locale data with km provides on @angular/common/locales

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-cfbv1v)

On your app.module.ts

```
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import km from '@angular/common/locales/km';

registerLocaleData(km);

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'km_KH' }],
})
export class AppModule {}
```